# unity falling sprite

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to figure out how to get my square (sprite) when I click on to fall and collide with my other square (sprite).
I know that I have to write a c# script to get it going with the Method:
private void OnMouseDown(){
}
but I don't know how to change the coordinates in this method please help !
Thanks,

[my whole projekt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwO54.jpg)

Comment: Show some code, and try to explain in a little more detail what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the coordinates of the transform the script is attached to (your player), you must access the transform. If you want to translate it, you should multiply it by `Time.deltaTime` to ensure that it will remain a constant speed at any framerate.

```
//On mouse down call
void OnMouseDown(){
     //Define your speed
     float speed = 1.0f;
     //Translate the y position downwards
     Vector3 newPos = this.transform.position;
     newPos.y -= Time.deltaTime * speed;
     this.transform.position.y = newPos.y;
}
```

**However, I'm not sure if you would even want this.** It would be a lot better if you set up 2D physics. To do this each object in the scene needs a collider and the player object must have a rigid body. To access these components go to the object and press *"Add Component"* towards the bottom. Here is an image of the dropdown that will appear:

[image: Unity component dropdown]

Then click the highlighted *"Physics 2D"*. Here you want to select "Box Collider 2D" for all the physics game objects and then only *"Rigidbody 2D"* for the player. When you start the game the 2D player should fall (if done correctly).

Comment: Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable

Comment: @LaurenzKaml Updated the code. I forgot that you couldn't change the transform position directly.